# how to prevent the app from creating a new listener if a listener already exists

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, event-listener

I am using firebase real time database in my android app . I  am having fragments in my app . I found that if I opened a fragment and its data loaded  and then I opened another fragment for about 5 second then reopen the first fragment again the data loads from the begging in the first fragment. I need a way to prevent this from happens since the listener isn't removed yet

Comment: Use DI or dependency injection. Dagger can help you out.

Comment: What do you mean through "the data loads from the begging"?